# URL building in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, url

My backend accepts http://url/api/rooms?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3&ids=4 and I'm trying to do a URL builder. My attempt is below but it ignores the rest of the parameters.

```
deleteRoom(ids: number[]) {
  console.log(ids);

  let params = new HttpParams();
  for (var id of ids) {
    params = params.set('ids', id);
  }

  console.log(`${this.actionUrl}?${params.toString()}`);

  return this.httpClient.delete(`${this.actionUrl}?${params.toString()}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to answer your question, it would be good you to show the result of your *console.log(`${this.actionUrl}?${params.toString()}`);* instruction.

Anyway, you could try to change *.set* for **.append**, like this:

```
params = params.append('ids', id);
```

Comment: `let params = new HttpParams();
    for (var id of ids) {
      params = params.append('ids', id);
    }` worked, thanks! :)

Comment: I am very glad it helped!